# how to launch activity after widget button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity

Following [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1732939) tutorial I quickly created a simple widget which displays the current time on the home screen:

[image]

I've modified the code so that the widget also comes with a button. My goal is to launch an activity, once the button get's pressed. 
Unfortunately, I do not really understand where to listen to the button click. Does this have to go into the broadcast receiver section of the manifest file?

```
<!--  Broadcast Receiver -->
<receiver android:name=".WifiSSIDWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/> 
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/wifi_ssid_widget_provider" />
</receiver>
```

Or does the code rather go into `onUpdate`? Here's the widget class code:

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
    }

    private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
        ComponentName thisWidget;
        DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, HelloWidget.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "TIME = " +format.format(new Date()));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    } 
}
```

Here's the code that I want to be called after the button is clicked:

```
public void openWifiSettings() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
...
public static final String ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICKED = "com.example.myapp.BUTTON1_CLICKED";
```

in `onUpdate` add the following to your button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICKED);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_1, pendingIntent);
```

and in `onReceive` of your AppWidget

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
 Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() " + intent.getAction());
 super.onReceive(context, intent);
...
if (ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction()))
{
 // your code
}
```

also add your intent to the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.example.myapp.BUTTON1_CLICKED" />
   ....
```

Comment: where should I define `ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICKED`? `PendingIntent` can also not be resolved. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on your solution?

Comment: `remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_1, pendingIntent);` gives me an error in the `onUpdate` method: `cannot be resolved`.

Comment: What's the exact error message? E.g. of course you have to add a button with id `button_1` to your widget layout.

Comment: `remoteViews cannot be resolved`. I guess that's because I create `remoteViews` in `public MyTime`. How should I change my code so it will still work?

Comment: Try to put these lines into your `run` method before calling `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget`. Maybe you have to make `remoteViews` final: `final RemoteViews remoteViews`

Comment: but I can not access `context` in `run`. Unless I do something like `this.context = context;` in the constructor. Is that ok?

Comment: add       RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);