# How to open browser by button on the widget?

Tags: android, browser, widget

I've a problem. When I try open browser by button on the widget:

```
public class Skrot extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
public void DW(View view){
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
} }
```

startActivity is underlined in red.

Image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/26PGt.png

Sorry for my bad English ;p

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651421/how-to-launch-activity-after-widget-button-is-pressed

Answer (score 0):

The `AppWidgetProvider` is a convenience class that implements a `BroadcastReceiver` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html for more details). Accordingly, there is no such method like `startActivity`. Instead you need to use a `context`.

It is not clear to me where you intent to call your method. Could you please provide details on that?

BTW: a nice introduction to developing widget can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html